# Spring can't seem to find spring-beans-x.y.xsd during startup

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, apache-camel

I've packaged my application and its dependencies in a jar, and when I start I get an error message as it seems Spring tries to fetch the schema files over http:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 123; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    ...
```

My Spring xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    ...
</beans>
```

When I search inside my jar I find these files:

```
/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

and I assume that the `factory/xml` part of the path is part of the problem? I start the (Apache Camel) application like so:

```
java -Dserver=acpt -jar my_app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -ac META-INF/spring/my_app.xml
```

Is my jar assembled incorrectly? Or need I somehow tell Spring about some path? Or should I set the classpath to something specific within the jar? Or might it be something to do with Camel (as I'm running `org.apache.camel.spring.Main`)? I really don't have a clue where to start, any suggestions welcome!

Comment: There is another file that keeps mapping of different xsd version files. You can check to which xsd it points. File is META-INF/spring.schemas

Comment: @Sanjeev: it does not contain any spring mappings (only camel ones). Could it be that maven/camel/something overwrites this file during build? [This guy](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/25596-cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-beans/page2) recommends writing my own spring.schemas. Is that my best bet do you think?

Comment: Spring looks into spring.schemas to find the appropriate xsd file if it does not find any than it tries to look over URL. It is worth giving a try to write your own

Comment: @Sanjeev: so I did, and it worked - thank you! Now I must come up with a way of replacing the file during the maven assembly build step...

Comment: Try to remove version. let spring decide appropriate xsd based on version you are using.

Comment: Glad it worked for you @Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I introduced a manual post-build patching step, I couldn't find any fix for this. The problem was that the `META-INF/spring.schemas` and `META-INF/spring.handlers` only contained the Camel stuff (overwritten at some point during build?), but not the Spring stuff.

I fixed this by creating two files, `missing.spring.handlers` and `missing.spring.schemas`, with the following contents:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
```

and

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler
```

Then I made a shell script which pretty much does:

```
cd target
unzip my.jar
cat path/to/missing.spring.handlers >>META-INF/spring.handlers
cat path/to/missing.spring.schemas  >>META-INF/spring.schemas
zip back my.jar again
```

Not a neat solution, but it works.

Comment: I think [maven-shade](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin) plugin may do this work